# Having trouble with web service call

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get theaters and movies to show up in my txtResults.Text box.

Here is my code right now...

```
 MovieInformation MI = new MovieInformation();

        int rad = int.Parse(txtRadius.Text);

        txtResults.Text = MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text, rad);
```

The error is: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebShowTimes.movies.Theater[]' to 'string'

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward.  Look at the definition for `GetTheatersAndMovies` and see what parameters it takes.

Comment: Check the `GetTheatersAndMovies' method and see how many parameters it takes. It is either going to take zero or more than one....

Comment: Okay now the method returns an array of Theater objects and you are trying to stuff that into a string.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler says that you are not passing the parameters expected by the service.

I suspect that your service will search for Theaters in an area (radius) around a certain zip code.

Have you tried

```
 txtResults.Text = MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text,txtRadius.Text);
```

EDIT: Seeing the new error message it is now clear that the method returns an array of `WebShowTimes.movies.Theater[]`

Of course this is not a string and cannot be used as value for a TextBox.Text property, so you need a loop to read each Theater returned and grab the property you need to show in the string

For Example:

```
WebShowTimes.movies.Theater[] theathers = MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text, rad);
foreach(WebShowTimes.movies.Theater t in theaters)
{
    txtResults.Text += t.Name + ", " + t.Address + "\r\n";
}
```

Assuming txtResult is a multiline textbox with enough height to show all the Theaters returned by the service.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. Check my edited post. I fixed the radius problem. Just having a problem with the zip now.

Answer (score 1):

Post the code for MovieInformation if you want more detailed help but the compiler is simply telling you that your `MovieInformation` service doesn't have a method called `GetTheatersAndMovies` that takes a single string parameter.

**EDIT:**

Based on the web service URL posted in your comment, you should be calling the web service as so:

```
 MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text,txtRadius.Text);
```

And you will be receiving an array of `Theater` objects that looks like this:

```
<Theater>
      <Name>string</Name>
      <Address>string</Address>
      <Movies>
        <Movie xsi:nil="true" />
        <Movie xsi:nil="true" />
      </Movies>
</Theater>
```

**Update 2** You should do something like this:

```
var result = MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text, rad);
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in result)
{
     sb.Append(string.Format("Theater Name: {0}",item.Name));
     sb.Append(string.Format("Address: {0}",item.Address));
     foreach (var movie in item.Movies)
     {
          sb.Append(string.Format("Movie: {0}",movie.Name));
          sb.Append(string.Format("Rating: {0}",movie.Rating));
     }
}

txtResults.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You can see the WSDL for the [web service here](http://www.ignyte.com/WebServices/Ignyte.WhatsShowing.Webservice/MovieFunctions.asmx?WSDL), which will tell you exactly how each object returned by the web service will look like.

Comment: http://www.ignyte.com/WebServices/Ignyte.WhatsShowing.Webservice/MovieFunctions.asmx

Comment: That's the web service I'm using.

Comment: So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't I be able to dump all the return info into the txtResults.Text ?

Comment: @MattMcCarthy no, because the web service returns a strongly typed object of type Theader[]. You need to iterate through the array and get the information you need. I will post another update to my answer.

Comment: I've tried the new updated code you posted. I got no errors, but when I hit the submit button nothing pops into the results box.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're calling the web method passing it 1 parameter, and there's no overload that takes 1 parameter. 
You probable need to make a new method that accept that parameter, and then use it properly. Or just remove the parameter that it's being passed

Answer (score 0):

The result returned is an array so get that in appropriate type and then loop it to get movies one by one something like:

```
MI.Theaters  th=MI.GetTheatersAndMovies(txtZip.Text, rad);
 foreach(Mi.movie in th)
   {
     string moviname=mi.movie.name;
   }
```

Hopefully this will give you the idea.